# Xamarin.Forms Page.Width half of what it should be during SizeChanged

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

In my ContentPage (which takes up the whole screen), I'm setting the `SizeChanged` event as follows:

```
private void init()
{
    EventHandler orientation_update_handler = (object sender, System.EventArgs e) =>
    {
        var binding_context = BindingContext as MyViewModel;
        binding_context?.OnOrientationChanged(Width, Height, Scale);
    };
    SizeChanged += orientation_update_handler;
    orientation_update_handler.Invoke(null, null);
    // other event handler setup...
```

Trying to set a breakpoint within `orientation_update_handler` but that's not getting hit...
Anyways; set a breakpoint in `OnOrientationChanged`. The width and height it's receiving are both half of what they actually are, and the scale always seems to be 1.

However, in my App delegate's `FinishedLaunching` function, while `UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Width` always seems to be the same as `ContentPage.Width`, `UIScreen.MainScreen.Scale` on the other hand is different to `ContentPage.Scale` and multiplying `UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Width` by `UIScreen.MainScreen.Scale` gives me the correct screen resolution of the device.

**Why is `ContentPage.Scale` always 1?** If it were the correct value, I could multiply by the width and get the correct screen resolution.

Answer (score 0):

> Why is ContentPage.Scale always 1? If it were the correct value, I could multiply by the width and get the correct screen resolution.

This is a misconception. Width and height are **not** given in physical pixels, see here

> Apple iPhone and iPad devices continue to work in units of points

and

> Android is similar. Programmers work in units of density-independent pixels (dps)

in both systems 160 units equate to one inch (or 64 units translate to 1 cm).

Comment: So how do I get the physical dimensions of the screen other than having to keep a reference to `UIScreen` and using that in my `ContentPage`?

Comment: What exactly do you need the physical dimensions for?

Comment: Do you use embedded Xamarin.Forms? Otherwise I don't see how you could use a reference to `UIScreen` in your `ContentPage`.

Comment: But you *could use* a custom renderer for a page derived from `ContentPage` that sets a custom property in your derived page.

Comment: I anticipate the need for physical dimensions when it comes to deciding font sizes, and background image size, etc. Besides the point, since it's only a 'virtual' desire and it doesn't harm anyone or disturb the peace. It's not really 'I'T, if I cannot have access to information :)

Comment: The great thing is, that XF can handle these things for you. You can define images for different resolutions and font sizes are determined in density pixels, too. I'll see if I can edit my answer accordingly later.

Comment: Regarding how I have access to UIScreen, we use MvvmCross, and a singleton is registered in the container that provides UIScreen info.